# ServiceStack.OrmLite support for IBM DB2

Tags: db2, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack.OrmLite with Oracle SQL dialect provider.
Do anybody knows if there is a SQL dialect provider for IBM DB2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't a provider for DB2, the 8 OrmLite Dialect Providers that are available are listed on the [OrmLite Home Page](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#download)

Comment: Do you plan do introduce one in the future?

Comment: @HubertR.Skrzypek It's unlikely as [there's no demand for it](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests).